# Chrome v.37. Native Messaging host tried sending a message that is 977472013 bytes long

Tags: java, google-chrome, chrome-native-messaging

I created a browser extension and my Native application. 
The language used to develop the Native application is **Java**, OS is **MS Windows 7**.
This works great in **Google Chrome** version **59**. But it does not start in version **37**.

In chrome version **37**, i execute the method `chrome.runtime.connectNative` in js code of extension and the native application simply will not start. 
That is, it immediately invokes a `onDisconnect` in the listener for the `Port` object.

If run **Google Chrome** with the logging key(`--enable-logging`), in *chrome_debug.log* there will be a record:

> :ERROR:native_message_process_host.cc(323) Native Messaging host tried
>   sending a message that is 977472013 bytes long.

There are similar questions:
[not mark solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909282/native-messaging-host-tried-sending-a-message-that-is-977472013-bytes-long), [the above explanation does not fit my situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906524/chrome-native-messaging-cannot-execute-batch-file), etc.
They do not explain the reasons for the lack of signs of launching Native application when using Google chome version 37

The problem is reproduced on all available workstations.
What is the difference in terms of working with the IO in Google Chrome version **59** and **37** ?

Is there really this difference?

Comment: 37 (released: 08/2014) vs 59 (released: 06/2017) that's probably a **huge** changelog.. Can't you just upgrade the 37 to 59?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not, these are the requirements. Moreover, all versions between 37 and 59 are required

Comment: Solved the problem, wrote a comment in the specified NOT resolved question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909282/native-messaging-host-tried-sending-a-message-that-is-977472013-bytes-long

Comment: 977472013 == "\r\nC:"